# Unable to locate FormController instance from parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

#### Problem

I'm trying to access an AngularJS FormController instance (created by setting a `name` property on a `form` directive) from it's parent controller scope. The output is `undefined`.

#### Confusion

But I can see the controller object as a property on the `$scope` when I log it to the console. I can also access the object from the template itself using the interpolation directive.

#### Example

The markup looks like:

```
<body ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <form name="FooForm" novalidate>
        <input name="bar" required>
    </form>
</body>
```

The JavaScript looks something like:

```
myAngularApp.controller('FooCtrl', function ($scope) {
    console.log($scope.FooForm); // undefined
    console.dir($scope); // has FooForm peek-a-booing in there
});
```

#### Demo

Here is the full plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/EE7pdBF32B5XRbjZuy8R?p=preview

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to follow these docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your controller is initialized before your template, so at the time you are trying to use it, it's still undefined. Try this:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('NewForm', function () {
        var outputArea = document.getElementById('output-area');
        outputArea.innerHTML = "The FormController instance is: " + $scope.NewForm;
    });
});
```

Also note that using:

```
outputArea.innerHTML = "The FormController instance is: " + console.dir(newVal);
```

Doesn't make much sense, you're trying to concat the return value of console.dir to a string, which also always returns undefined ;) Changed it to:

```
outputArea.innerHTML = "The FormController instance is: " + $scope.NewForm;
```

Here's a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yfVP8hD6saWV2tIok2ER?p=preview

Edit after comment:

If you want to be notified as soon as the form is available on your scope and you don't want to use $watch, you could do that by adding an custom directive to your form element which fires an event:

```
<form name="NewForm" novalidate formready>
```

The custom 'formready' directive:

```
.directive('formready', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function () {
            return {
                post: function(scope) {
                    scope.$emit('formready');
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Now in your controller you can do:

```
$scope.$on('formready', function (event) {
    console.log($scope.NewForm); // Available now
});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KG7LEB6EEkBkdONkL9LA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Does the extra `$watch` cause a performance degrade? Is there  a way to avoid this and still achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: I've added code with another example using $emit not $watch.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by referencing the form this way? Could you not simply use ngModel on the form and leverage 2 way data binding to access the value in the controller?

Comment: @smaira it was mostly for accessing form validation state in the controller (some fields in particular).

Comment: I see. Maybe ngMesssage can help with that.